# DSNLess database connection

Tags: java

How to make a DSN less Connection in JAVA. I am trying to make SQL database connection in my java program. But i dont want to make DSN. Is there any alternative. Or how can i make DSN command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type IV, 100% Java JDBC driver for your database and dispense with a DSN altogether.  which SQL database are you using?  If you meant "Microsoft SQL Server", you can choose either the [Microsoft JDBC driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724) or [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).